# Dynamic Drop Down List in ColdFusion 9

Tags: html, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cascadingdropdown

Alright so people were not understanding clearly my question, so I removed the url where there was a question already asked by someone else and there I didn't got the perfect answer..

So here is the Question........

I am looking to code a dynamic drop down list within ColdFusion. What I want is the drop down list to be populated by the above drop down list (example: Select Province (B.C) will populate the City drop down list with all cities within that Province). Province data will be collected from a ColdFusion query and same with the city's data.

Please, No JavaScript, No AJAX, No ColdFusion CFCs, Nothing more than or less than some ColdFusion Tags... :( The logic code should be in one .cfm file itself.

- Edit -

@Charles Higgins

Can't seem to make it work. It's throwing "Error invoking CFC BinFcns.cfc : Internal Server Error" "Please tell me where I'm doing it wrong, here is the code..

This one is 'index.cfm'

```
<cfquery name="qstates" datasource="info">
  SELECT states
  FROM info

  GROUP BY states
</cfquery> 
<html> 
<head> 
</head> 
<body> 
<cfform>
<cfselect name="DropDown1" bind="cfc:BinFcns.Method({DropDown1})">
    <cfoutput query="qstates"><option>#states#</option></cfoutput>
</cfselect>
<cfselect name="DropDown2" bind="cfc:BinFcns.Method({DropDown1})" /> 
</cfform>
</body> 
</html>
```

and this one is the .cfc, 'BinFcns.cfc'

```
<cfcomponent output="true">
   <!--- set function name --->
   <cffunction name="Method" access="remote" returnType="array">
    <!--- this is what you passed to the CFC via the {} think in the select --->
      <cfargument name="Selected" type="numeric" required="true">
      <!--- Define array to produce the drop down --->
      <cfset var data="">
      <cfset var result=ArrayNew(2)>
      <cfset var i=0>
      <!--- Get data --->
      <cfquery name="data" datasource="info">
      SELECT *
      FROM info
      Order by cities
      </cfquery> 
      <!--- Convert results to array --->
      <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#data.RecordCount#">
             <cfset result[i][1]=data.DropDownID[i]>
             <cfset result[i][2]='#DropDownTEXT#'>      
             <!--- determine which is selected via what you passed and something in the database --->
            <cfif data.DropDownID[i] eq #Selected#>
                <cfset result[i][3]=true>
            </cfif>
      </cfloop>

      <!--- And return it --->
      <cfreturn result>
   </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CFC Its not complicated, trust me learn its the best option, I have not tested this code but it should be close to working.. just fugly like most of my code.

```
<cfcomponent output="false">
   <!--- set function name --->
   <cffunction name="Method" access="public" returnType="array">
    <!--- this is what you passed to the CFC via the {} think in the select --->
      <cfargument name="Selected" type="numeric" required="true">
      <!--- Define array to produce the drop down --->
      <cfset var data="">
      <cfset var result=ArrayNew(2)>
      <cfset var i=0>
      <!--- Get data --->
      <cfquery name="data" datasource="#THIS.dsn#">
      SELECT *
      FROM 2ndDropDownData
      Order by DataName
      </cfquery> 
      <!--- Convert results to array --->
      <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#data.RecordCount#">
             <cfset result[i][1]=data.DropDownID[i]>
             <cfset result[i][2]='#DropDownTEXT#'>      
             <!--- determine which is selected via what you passed and something in the database --->
            <cfif data.DropDownID[i] eq #Selected#>
                <cfset result[i][3]=true>
            </cfif>
      </cfloop>

      <!--- And return it --->
      <cfreturn result>
   </cffunction>
</cffunction>
```

The CFM SIMPLE!

A drop down called DropDown1, then you pass that to the cfc via the following code for drop down 2

```
<cfselect name="DropDown2" bind="cfc:cfcname.Method({DropDown1})" />
```

Its that simple... two drop downs, with the second one calling the CFC.. Worth learning.

You can use Bindonload, on the 2nd to preselect if required.

Anyway hope that stops you being scared of CFCs.. they are very usefull.

Comment: Oh this might help...http://www.asfusion.com/blog/entry/two-selects-related-in-cfform

Comment: That link is for flash forms, not html. BTW, CF8.0.1+ cfselect binds support queries, not just arrays. Simply return the query from your cfc and you are done. Unfortunately no `"selected"` attribute support until CF9 I think.

Comment: I'm still getting errors.. I've pasted the code above please cross check it once... Thanks a lot for the help, it really matters to me.

Comment: Its not designed for cut and paste, just to inform you of the bits you need to put in. If you want a more detailed overview, drop me a line and I`ll talk you though it. Screw it.. I`m determined to solve this one issue for you I`m going to upload the code...  and post a link to a demo.

Comment: Above is an example, and the code... combine that with the original example.. but that is as simple as I can make it. I worked all this out originally with a copy of Ben Forta WHACK + Google. You`ll need to combine my original example + the link, to get it working how you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort to help me out. :)

Answer (score 0):

I usually just write my own AJAX call with jQuery so I'm not too familiar with ColdFusion's data binding. The CFC / NOT CFC concept is the same really. You're requesting data from the server, if you used a .cfm file or a .cfc to return the data your code would be very similar.

from [CFSelect Docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/ajaxdata_03.html#1128486), The return must be:

> - A two-dimensional array, where the first element in each array row is    the option value and the second element in the row is the text
>     to    display in the option list.
> - If the bind specifies a CFC function, a    query, or, if the bind specifies a URL, a JSON representation of a    query. The query must
>     include columns whose names are the values of    the cfselect tag
>     value and display attributes. Although you can    return additional
>     columns, you cannot use them in your client-side    code. When you
>     call a CFC function, you do not have to convert the    query to JSON
>     format yourself; ColdFusion automatically does the    conversion. To
>     use this format, you must specify a value attribute.    If you omit
>     the display attribute, you must have only a single column    in the
>     query that contains the values; the values are also used as    the
>     displayed text.

From [Binding data to form fields](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/ajaxdata_03.html#1128486):

> *Using bind expressions* To specify a bind expression, use one of the
>   following formats:
>
> - cfc:componentPath.functionName(parameters) *Note:* The component path
>     cannot use a mapping. The componentPath value must be a dot-delimited
>     path from the web root or the directory that contains the current
>     page.
> - javascript:functionName(parameters)
> - url:URL?parameters
> - URL?parameters
> - A string containing one or more instances of {bind
>     parameter}, such as {firstname}.{lastname}@{domain}

Comment: Isn't there any pure ColdFusion Tag way to achieve this result without using any JavaScript or Ajax?

Comment: I'm new to ColdFusion.. And I don't know CFC thing.. :( :((

Comment: I think you should still be able to use cfselect but instead of binding to a cfc try binding to a url that returns an array. The dependant bind might look something like `bind="url:getCities.cfm?state={state}"`

Comment: I could be wrong here, like I said I'm not overly experienced with the cfform stuff.  Personally I just don't like it.  Honestly though, CFCs aren't hard, it's basically just a collection of functions. They're a pretty integral part of CF so you may as well bite the bullet and get to know the CFC thing.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your page you could write a `cfquery` that would hit your database and retrieve the data. Then inside the page you can utilize the `cfselect` tag with its query attribute and this should populate the select box with values pulled from your `cfquery`.

This will allow your to quickly generate pages but it's not very reusable and is generally considered poor practice. I tend to stay away from any of the `cfselect`,`cfform`, etc tags. I also add my `cfquery` to a central .cfc file so they can be accessed throughout the site. This will save you time when the query changes and you are hunting throughout the site for where you made that specific call.

Anyway hope this helps, if you have any questions fire away!

---Edit---

In response to your updated question. You could have two `cfquery` tags on your page. One would fire on the first load of the page and populate the Province list. Upon selection this would submit a form and set a URL variable. You could then pass that variable to your second `cfquery` that would then populate the City list. The code sample provided by the user above me would work in this regard.

Again hope this helps, if you want specific code I can provide it but that logic should get you going on the right path.

Comment: Please provide with the specific code if you can because no theory is going in my head right now. I would be really grateful to you... Thanks a billion times in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I am sure some people will scream in horror, but here is something I used to do as a newbie if you want a dynamic select.

Query the Table, to get values

```
<cfquery datasource="xy" name="get">
 Select *
 From Data
</cfquery>
```

Just stick the output inside the select, and if you want to be cocky use a CFIF to determine which bit you are viewing. You do not need to use CFSELECT, select can do.

```
<cfselect name="select">
  <cfoutput query="get">
    <option value="#URLTAKENFROMDATABASE#"
    <cfif #CGI.SCRIPT_NAME# eq '#URLTAKENFROMDATABASE#'>selected</cfif>
     >#LINKNAME#</option
  </cfoutput>
</cfselect>
```

You can Group your query or your output to stick in sub headers within the drop down for example something like

```
<cfoutput query"get" group="SECTIONA">
  <option value="">#SECTIONA#</option>
      <cfoutput>
        <option value="#URLTAKENFROMDATABASE#"
        <cfif #CGI.SCRIPT_NAME# eq '#URLTAKENFROMDATABASE#'>selected</cfif>
         >#LINKNAME#</option
      </cfoutput>   
</cfouput>
```

Comment: What this code is doing? Can you please explain?

<option value="#URLTAKENFROMDATABASE#"
    <cfif #CGI.SCRIPT_NAME# eq '#URLTAKENFROMDATABASE#'>selected</cfif>
     >#LINKNAME#</option

Comment: [{lions and tigers and # signs oh my..}](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:The_Scream.jpg). Good overview. But if you are using `cfselect`, may as well just use the "query" and "selected" attributes and skip the manually generated <options>.

Comment: @Nayeem - Keep in mind Charles just described how to populate a `<select>` list. To *automatically* "relate" two select lists, the way you described, you **must** use some javascript.

Comment: @Leigh hmmmmm :( really? I hate to hear that.. btw Do you know what group attribute of cfoutput does? Could it be helpful here?

Comment: I never said it was pretty I did it that way as back then I could adjust the validator to reject "" blank results at the top to force a selection. 
Anyway, Nayeem Look up how a select works in html... all your doing is filling the options via an cfoutput rather than a static list. the <CFIF you can ignore as that is just used to tell which option is the default (ie which is selected) it is not required, does that help at all?

Comment: Leigh is right, I missed that.. if you want two related you really need to use java. Or you can just use a CFC.. I will go grab some old code for Leigh to scream at some more and update my post.

Comment: Haha, the link was a joke at your "some people will scream in horror" comment ;-) Most old code has an abundance of excess of # signs. Mine included.

Comment: @NayeemJunaid - Why? Javascript is a big part of web development, so it is something you have to learn at some point. No time like the present.

Comment: @Leigh I know that.. But I just want to utilize the true potential of ColdFusion and want only ColdFusion way.

Comment: @NayeemJunaid - I think you are mixing up client and server side language capabilities. It cannot be done with CF. *Automatically* refreshing a select list, when the user selects something from another list, is something that takes place in the browser. That requires a client side language such as javascript. CF is a server side language. Like any server side language (.net, php, etcetera) it runs on the server and *cannot* execute code in the browser. (continued ..)

Comment: Features like binding to a CFC make things easier, by automatically generating all of the necessary javascript for you behind the scenes. However, they still use javascript to *automatically* refresh the list upon certain user actions.

Comment: @Leigh Yes, I want ColdFusion to generate JavaScript automatically, I don't want to generate it myself.

Comment: @Nayeem - Well as mentioned in the comments, it is not cut and paste code. You need to substitute *your* own column names in the cffunction code - and test it idependently. We cannot really offer anything more specific without seeing your db table structure.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can have your first dropdown bind to a cfc or populated from a query on your page, but not both.  Either method will work, pick one.

Next, your `Method` function in your cfc has an argument but doesn't use it properly.  Your `cfquery` should use it in the `where` clause.  Also, don't try to pre-select any city.  It doesn't make sense in the context of cascading selects.