# populating select based on previous select - how to run the query after selection

Tags: select, drop-down-menu, coldfusion

I'm running Coldfusion 10,0,8,284032 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter with SQL Server 2012 as a datasource.

I'd like to create two selects on a form.  One which has the name of wildlife preserves and another that lists the trails in that preserve after the preserve has been selected.  I have the preserves and trails in a db table dbo.reserveandtrail which has cols for ID, trailname and reservename.

The thing I'm having an issue with is how to issue a query to select the trails when the preserve has been selected on the dropdown.  Would it be possible to accomplish this simply using CF or should I be looking into JS/Ajax?

Comment: There are plenty of examples out there... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13414175/dynamic-drop-down-list-in-coldfusion-9 for a sample.

Comment: I find the bind attribute of cfinput or cfselect to be a very simple way to accomplish this.  Google either of those tags for examples.  Make sure that you get your queries and cfc functions working before attempting to use them with ajax.

Comment: You can do it using CF only but the form will refresh and jump to another page and it'll look so 90s.

Comment: unless you're forced to, I would not use cfinput or cfselect. Use JavaScript to call your cfc's

Comment: Matt and I appear to have different opinions.  I think that proves that we are each able to form one.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly either works well (jQuery/Ajax or Coldfusion's built in ajax functions). It really depends on the project. If you are not currently relying heavily on jQuery within the application, then Coldfusion is probably quickest to implement and there are no dependencies/imports.

If the cfc functions are built correctly, they will work with either so they can be used interchangeably with either method.

Here is a quick Coldfusion demonstration... hope it helps.

====html

```
<cfform name="test" >
    <cfselect name="option1">
        <option value="">--please select--</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </cfselect>
    <cfselect name="option2" display="suboption_display" value="suboption_value" bindOnLoad="true" bind="cfc:webroot.jquery.stackoverflow.cascadingselect.applogic.select_binding({option1})" ></cfselect>
</cfform>
```

==cfc

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="select_binding" access="remote" returntype="query">
        <cfargument name="selected_option" type="string" required="yes">

        <cfset dataset = QueryNew('suboption_display,suboption_value','CF_SQL_VARCHAR,CF_SQL_INTEGER')>

        <cfswitch expression="#arguments.selected_option#">
            <cfcase value="1">
                <cfset r = queryaddrow(dataset,3)>
                <cfset temp = querysetcell(dataset, 'suboption_display', 'black', 1)> 
                <cfset temp = querysetcell(dataset, 'suboption_value', 1, 1)> 
                <cfset temp = querysetcell(dataset, 'suboption_display', 'white', 2)> 
                <cfset temp = querysetcell(dataset, 'suboption_value', 2, 2)> 
                <cfset temp = querysetcell(dataset, 'suboption_display', 'gray', 3)> 
                <cfset temp = querysetcell(dataset, 'suboption_value', 3, 3)> 
             </cfcase>
            <cfcase value="2">
                <cfset r = queryaddrow(dataset,3)>
                <cfset temp = querysetcell(dataset, 'suboption_display', 'red', 1)> 
                <cfset temp = querysetcell(dataset, 'suboption_value', 1, 1)> 
                <cfset temp = querysetcell(dataset, 'suboption_display', 'blue', 2)> 
                <cfset temp = querysetcell(dataset, 'suboption_value', 2, 2)> 
                <cfset temp = querysetcell(dataset, 'suboption_display', 'green', 3)> 
                <cfset temp = querysetcell(dataset, 'suboption_value', 3, 3)> 
            </cfcase>
            <cfcase value="3">
                <cfset r = queryaddrow(dataset,3)>
                <cfset temp = querysetcell(dataset, 'suboption_display', 'yellow', 1)> 
                <cfset temp = querysetcell(dataset, 'suboption_value', 1, 1)> 
                <cfset temp = querysetcell(dataset, 'suboption_display', 'orange', 2)> 
                <cfset temp = querysetcell(dataset, 'suboption_value', 2, 2)> 
                <cfset temp = querysetcell(dataset, 'suboption_display', 'purple', 3)> 
                <cfset temp = querysetcell(dataset, 'suboption_value', 3, 3)> 
            </cfcase>
            <cfdefaultcase>
                <cfset r = queryaddrow(dataset,1)>
                <cfset temp = querysetcell(dataset, 'suboption_display', '--please select option--', 1)> 
                <cfset temp = querysetcell(dataset, 'suboption_value', 0, 1)> 
            </cfdefaultcase>
        </cfswitch>

        <cfreturn dataset>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```